# Handling Exchange Web Services (EWS) missing properties

Tags: linq, properties, exchangewebservices

I'm relatively comfortable with EWS programming and Exchange schemas, but running into an interesting problem to handle.

I have a `propertyset`, asking for:

- `ItemClass`
- `DateTimeReceived`
- `LastModifiedTime`
- `Size`
- Every Item in the `AllItems` folder at the root.

I get the result set, and then attempt Linq queries against the set, particular to the DateTimeReceived.  All Items don't have a DateTimeReceived returned by the server, and they except.  I'm trying a...

```
long msgCount = (from msg in allItems 
                 where !msg.DateTimeReceived.Equals(null) 
                 select msg).Count();
```

... which (IMO) should return the count of allItems that have a DateTimeReceived.  However, the property isn't null; it's just not there, throwing an exception.

I'm trying to avoid iterating through the set one by one, trying each record.  Anyone have a thought or experience?

Comment: Have you tried doing GetType().GetProperty() or .GetType().GetRuntimeProperty() on msg, to see if the property actually exists.

Comment: I've considered along with the TryGetProperty, but each of these m/l mandates abandonment of Linq, doesn't it?  Thanks for the response; I appreciate any perspective.

Comment: you dont' have to write linq always as from... . You can do something like allItems.Where (x=> { logic check if it exists  return boolean }). Select(x=> x).Count()

Answer (score 0):

Thanks TTY for the input that definitely lead to the following code that returns what I need.  (Still in final testing)

```
List<EWS.Item> noReceivedProperty = inputlist.Where(m => (m.GetType().GetProperty("DateTimeReceived") != null)).ToList<EWS.Item>();
```

Then of course, take noReceivedProperty.Count or such as needed.